# AWS SQL Server stopped connecting after few hours. What can be the reason?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, timeout, cloud, amazon-rds

Yesterday I acquired a SQL Server instance on AWS and managed to connect using below.

[image]

I even managed to create a new database, create table and insert data. After few hours when I went back it has started timing out like below with message like below.

[image]

I see SQL Server available in AWS GUI

[image]

Comment: Error 258 is a client-side timeout error (see `net helpmsg 258`) which suggests that your client computer is unable to connect to the remote server. When you get this error in SSMS are you also seeing `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName myrdstest.c1dszhndq83j.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -Port 1433` fail in a PowerShell window? Have you added rules to the `sg-0875daa58496479fc` security group that could be blocking access from your current IP address? (You can check your current public IP address by visiting sites like ipchicken.com in a web browser.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning IP seems to be issue. IP in Inbound rule source is different then what i see on ipchicken.com, may be my ISP changed IP. Can I set Inbound rule to accept connection from any IP?

Comment: Try editing the security group to add an allow rule using your current public IP address as the source.

Comment: Your ISP DHCP gave you new public IP which is not whitelisted in the RDS security group (myrdstest)
Side note: publicly accessible RDS is a very bad idea.